# Alternative for collections in .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a project in .NET, using the old .NET 2.0 framework unfortunately (due to the difficulty of updating many clients, validate a newer version of the framework to install in many computers, etc...).

I have seen that the majority of collection classes are from the .NET 4 framework.
What would you recommend to use if I need Sets and Maps but I would need to use .NET 2.0 framework? Should I implement from scratch every collection that I would like to use?

Are there more collections apart from System.Collections.Generic namespace that I do not know? (Reference here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I guess the best decision would be to convince the necessary people to update all the clients to 4.5 .NET framework because this will bring more developing possibilities, and this version would bring many improvements. But I am not sure that I will be able to change this. So what would you do in my position?

Thank you for reading.
Regards.

Comment: I must have misunderstood you. If you want "Maps" in .NET 2.0 there is the [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class. As for sets, you can use `Dictionary<TKey, bool>` since you unfortunately don't have `HashSet<T>` in .NET 2.0 (as far as I know).

Comment: 4.5 is not supported on windows XP, but 4.0 is. The difference between 2.0 and 4.0 is HUGE. I suggest you think about the possibility of using 4.0

Comment: What *specific* collections do you need?

Comment: @odyss-jii `HashSet` was added in 3.5.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I need Sets primarily.
@odyss-jii I guess your option could replace the set perfectly.

Comment: Although it seems a bit messy to use Dictionary for that. Does anybody know any alternatives to have a Set?

Comment: You could implement `HashSet<TKey>` yourself using an underlying `Dictionary<TKey, bool>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` are available in .NET 2.0. So as most of other generic collections. Instead of `HashSet<T>` you can use generic dictionary. Also you don't need to implement it from scratch. You can delegate most part of functionality to dictionary. E.g.

```
public class HashSet<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, object> _dictionary = new Dictionary<T, object>();

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        if (!_dictionary.ContainsKey(value))
            _dictionary.Add(value, null);
    }

    public void Remove(T value)
    {
        _dictionary.Remove(value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public int Count 
    { 
        get { return _dictionary.Count; } 
    }

    public IEnumerator<T>  GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dictionary.Keys.GetEnumerator();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> I have seen that the majority of collection classes are from the .NET 4 framework.

That's simply not true. The `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace came into play in .NET 4, but *most* of the generic collections arrived in .NET 2.

.NET 3.5 only had a few new ones - I suspect the most important one being `HashSet<T>`.

The most *commonly* used collections (aside from arrays) are probably:

- `List<T>`
- `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`
- `LinkedList<T>`
- `Queue<T>`
- `Stack<T>`

... with the first two being *way* more widely used than the last three. All of these were in .NET 2.

The other important difference to be aware of is LINQ: .NET 3.5 introduced LINQ, but you *can* use an alternative implementation of LINQ to Objects (e.g. [LINQBridge](https://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/)) against .NET 2.0. This works well if you've got a modern version of Visual Studio, allowing you to use some *language* features from C# 3 and higher even while you target .NET 2.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You are right, it is not the majority of collection classes. I was looking mainly for Set implementations. That is why I felt that there was something important left in 2.0 version (HashSet and SortedSet). Maybe Sets are the only collection that I will miss in 2.0 (but it was the one that I needed first). Although my problem with maps could be covered with Dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: @pablof: If you wanted sets, you should have said that in your question. Please be more specific in future.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have been more specific. Thank you for your time. You answer has been very useful too : ) 
Only sets were the only ones that .NET 2 did not have, and I will also try LINQBridge.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `Wintellect's Power Collections for .NET`, http://powercollections.codeplex.com/

It is a replacement for .net 4 , but it has few very handy collections.